# Java reference outer Class scope in callback

Tags: java

In class `Foo`, I'm performing an HTTP post, returning to a callback:

```
class Foo {

    private static void send() {

        HttpPostRequest task = new HttpPostRequest(data, new HttpPostRequest.CustomCallback() {
            @Override
            public void completionHandler(Boolean success, String result) {

                // this doesn't work
                // this.anotherMethod();
            }
        });
        task.execute("https://foo.org");
    }

    private static void anotherMethod() {
      // i need to do things here...
    }

}
```

This callback works, however I need to call another method in the outer class scope. I can't figure out how to do this: How do I properly reference this outer scope?

Answer (score 1):

When both methods are static you can simply call:

```
Foo.anotherMethod()
```

if both are not static, you can do:

```
Foo.this.anotherMethod()
```

Comment: Will this also reference instance variables? Such as `this.myVariable` in the outer class instance?

Comment: @dthree that's the second option I mentioned (which is feasible only if both methods are *not* static). When a method is static it does not refer to *any* instance since it's a class-method not an instance-method.